# Make a static method accessible via URL with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I've got a Spring Roo-application (which uses Spring MVC for the scaffolded views) and I would like to execute a static method upon accessing a specific URL.

How can I pull this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does it have to do anything with Spring Roo. I thought it was only applicable at Compile Time and not at runtime?

In Spring MVC you can create a @Controller and then give the method  @RequestMapping(value="/url", method = RequestMethod.GET) .

Check out http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html for more reference.